# Save XML response in MySQL using Python

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing

I am trying to save a xml response into MySQL database using python, but I am kinda stuck and I did lot of research on net. Since my Python coding knowledge is kinda limited not sure why I am getting weird result.

```
<site siteID="0404">
        <date dateValue="20190322">
            <traffic code="01" exits="0" enters="0" startTime="000000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="0" enters="0" startTime="010000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="0" enters="0" startTime="020000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="0" enters="0" startTime="030000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="0" enters="0" startTime="040000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="0" enters="0" startTime="050000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="0" enters="0" startTime="060000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="0" enters="0" startTime="070000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="0" enters="0" startTime="080000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="1" enters="2" startTime="090000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="17" enters="21" startTime="100000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="18" enters="16" startTime="110000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="20" enters="26" startTime="120000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="23" enters="25" startTime="130000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="13" enters="18" startTime="140000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="22" enters="21" startTime="150000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="26" enters="23" startTime="160000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="23" enters="22" startTime="170000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="21" enters="19" startTime="180000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="30" enters="35" startTime="190000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="9" enters="9" startTime="200000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="0" enters="0" startTime="210000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="0" enters="0" startTime="220000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="0" enters="0" startTime="230000"/>
        </date>
    </site>
    <site siteID="0406">
        <date dateValue="20190322">
            <traffic code="01" exits="0" enters="0" startTime="000000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="0" enters="0" startTime="010000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="0" enters="0" startTime="020000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="0" enters="0" startTime="030000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="0" enters="0" startTime="040000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="0" enters="0" startTime="050000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="0" enters="0" startTime="060000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="0" enters="0" startTime="070000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="0" enters="0" startTime="080000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="5" enters="8" startTime="090000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="24" enters="27" startTime="100000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="34" enters="35" startTime="110000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="22" enters="21" startTime="120000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="13" enters="12" startTime="130000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="40" enters="43" startTime="140000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="21" enters="15" startTime="150000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="18" enters="21" startTime="160000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="12" enters="11" startTime="170000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="12" enters="6" startTime="180000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="5" enters="7" startTime="190000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="6" enters="2" startTime="200000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="0" enters="0" startTime="210000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="0" enters="0" startTime="220000"/>
            <traffic code="01" exits="0" enters="0" startTime="230000"/>
        </date>
    </site>
```

Desired result is

```
siteID  dateValue   exits   enters  startTime
404     20190322     0        0      0000
404     20190322     0        0      10000
404     20190322     0        0      20000
404     20190322     0        0      30000
404     20190322     1        2      90000
```

What I start with,

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

parsedXML  = ET.parse('File/demo.xml')
root = parsedXML .getroot()

for demoxml in root.findall('site'):
    store = demoxml .get('siteID')
    date = demoxml .find('date')
    trafiic = demoxml .find('traffic')
    print(store, date, trafiic)
```

I am getting (result),

```
0404 <Element 'date' at 0x00000194EBE12D18> None
0406 <Element 'date' at 0x00000194EBE15598> None
100 <Element 'date' at 0x00000194EBE15DB8> None
101 <Element 'date' at 0x00000194EBE1A638> None
102 <Element 'date' at 0x00000194EBE1AE58> None
105 <Element 'date' at 0x00000194EBE1E6D8> None
106 <Element 'date' at 0x00000194EBE1EEF8> None
200 <Element 'date' at 0x00000194EBE23778> None
201 <Element 'date' at 0x00000194EBE23F98> None
203 <Element 'date' at 0x00000194EBE26818> None
205 <Element 'date' at 0x00000194EBE26DB8> None
206 <Element 'date' at 0x00000194EBE06638> None
301 <Element 'date' at 0x00000194EBE06E58> None
302 <Element 'date' at 0x00000194EBE2E6D8> None
303 <Element 'date' at 0x00000194EBE2EEF8> None
305 <Element 'date' at 0x00000194EBE52778> None
```

Can anybody please tell me what I am doing wrong and how do I get me desired result? I think something wrong with the elements and attributes, but not sure.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results from the XML parser are nested elements. So, the final working code below uses three for loops (to access site, date, and traffic level data).
After adding an html tag to your sample data, you can see the hierarchy by printing root, root[0], root[0][0], and list(root[0][0]) which give the html, site, date, and traffic elements respectively. The get method will then return the data from the named field specified.  Alternatively, one could use indexing and dictionary key values. For example:  root[0].attrib['siteID'] to get the siteID value "0404" and root[1].attrib['siteID'] to yield "406" as well as all the remaining data.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

parsedXML  = ET.parse('File/demo.xml')
root = parsedXML.getroot()enter code here

print('siteID \t dateValue \t exits \t enters \t startTime')

for demoxml in root.findall('site'):
    siteID = demoxml.get('siteID')
    for date in demoxml:
        dateValue = date.get('dateValue')
        for item in date:
            exits = item.get('exits')
            enters = item.get('enters')
            startTime = item.get('startTime')
            print('{} \t {} \t {} \t {} \t\t {}'.format(siteID, dateValue, exits, enters, startTime))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick respond. One last question, I ma getting out put from API.

`response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)`
`parsedXML  = ET.parse(response)`

then I put the code yo created it will give me an error. Please see below comment

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ suneth  /Demo_XML/demoxml.py", line 33, in <module>
    parsedXML  = ET.parse(response)
  File "C:\Users\suneth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1195, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "C:\Users\Suneth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 585, in parse
    source = open(source, "rb")
TypeError: invalid file: <Response [200]>

Process finished with exit code 1`

Comment: Do you happen to know why is that? I will get the same xml response back when I put `print(response )` 
Thank you so much for your help and time

Comment: The response from the request is an 'requests.models.Response' object.  But, I believe the ET.parse takes only XML format.  You may need to further process the object (i.e., response = response.json() will convert the object into a JSON file, then you need to convert the JSON into XML).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This exactly what I want. Again, thank you